# jquery validate field for full name

Tags: jquery, validation, text

I want to make a jquery validation for 'full name' field, which by my definition is a minimum of two words, but not limited to two, no numbers of course.

```
 function validateFullName()
 {
 var fullname=document.forms["CollectData"]["FullName"].value;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. This function will return `true` if the given string has at least two words considering that a word has at least 2 characters.

```
var isName = function(str){
    var match = str.match(/\b[A-Za-z]{2,}\b/g);
    return match.length > 1;
};
```

You could also use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) or [jq-idealforms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms), a little plugin I made for forms and stuff, it has validation too.

Comment: doesnt trigger if value is ='DD1' or anything where the first word has a number

Comment: well I assumed it was a person's name, which wouldn't include numbers. To include numbers just change the regex to `/\b\w{2,}\b/`

Comment: not working... i'll explain again exactly what i want... to return TRUE only if a string has at least two words, with each word having at least 2 chars, and to return false if any numerics in the string